# How to clear firebase database entries or entry?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing an app on Android and it creates some data and stores in a  database created in the firebase. But I needed to have a functionality where I can delete all the data in that database. Earlier there was a method called 'Firebase.remove()', but its not available now or a proper documentation is missing.  So it would be great if someone can suggest a way

Comment: if you want to remove the entire node or db or just an object, just import an empty JSON file

Answer (score 7):

From "...I can delete all the data in that database...", I assume you want to empty the root element.

Now, to remove any object from Firebase Database, first have reference to that key of Database or Database itself, say

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Now you have two ways to achieve what you want:

1. removeValue(): `databaseReference.removeValue();`
2. setValue(): `databaseReference.setValue(null);`

Answer (score 4):

You can delete a root node by calling delete on it:

```
Firebase firebaseRef = new Firebase("myfirebase.com");
firebaseRef.child("node").remove();
```